# how to get list of folders that older then 30 days

Tags: bash, date, awk, sed

we have the following example list - `/tmp/file`  while the first field represented the date , and the second field represented the folder path

our target is to get only the list of folders that older then 30 days from current day

we tried with bash that include sort and awk/sed but without success

```
more /tmp/file

2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0046
2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0049
2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0051
2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0063
2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0064
2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0065
2023-09-18 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0107
2023-09-18 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0108
2023-09-18 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0109
2023-09-19 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0142
2023-09-19 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0143
2023-10-11 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1697021506895_0001
2023-10-11 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1697021506895_0002
2023-10-11 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1697021506895_0017
2023-10-12 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1697021506895_0048
2023-10-12 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1697021506895_0054
2023-10-12 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1697021506895_0062
2023-10-12 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1697021506895_0063
2023-10-15 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1697021506895_0077
2023-10-15 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1697021506895_0081
2023-10-15 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1697021506895_0090
2023-10-16 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1697021506895_0170
2023-10-16 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1697021506895_0171
2023-10-19 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1697021506895_0422
2023-10-19 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1697021506895_0426
```

Comment: Could you share some of your bash/awk/sed code and what issues did you encounter?

Comment: And add the expected output. Please provide a [mcve] in all questions.

Comment: Have you considered using `find` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't normally post an answer to a question that shows neither the OPs attempt in code nor the expected output but since there's other answers already....

Using GNU date plus any awk:

```
$ awk -v d="$(date -d '-30 days' +'%F')" '$1 < d' file
2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0046
2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0049
2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0051
2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0063
2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0064
2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0065
2023-09-18 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0107
2023-09-18 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0108
2023-09-18 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0109
```

or using GNU awk (for time functions `systime()` and `strftime()`) alone:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{d=strftime("%F",systime()-30*24*60*60)} $1 < d' file
2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0046
2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0049
2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0051
2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0063
2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0064
2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0065
2023-09-18 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0107
2023-09-18 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0108
2023-09-18 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0109
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `date` to get the date 30 days ago.

```
date -d '-30 days'
```

To get it in the same format the file uses, specify the format as `+%Y-%m-%d`.

You can use `sort` to sort the dates, as the YYYY-MM-DD format sorts asciibetically. If you include the created date into the list, you are interested in all the dates after it, so you can use `sed` to remove everything up to it. To do that, you can use the `d` command with an address range, deleting from the first line up to a matched line.

To detect where the date is in the list, I used `///` to mark the inserted date, as it can never be part of a path:

```bash
{
    echo
    date -d '-30 days' +%Y-%m-%d' ///'
    cat /tmp/file
} | LC_ALL=C sort | sed '1,\=///=d'
```

*Updated:* I also added an empty line which will always sort first so that it works even if *all* the lines should be printed (otherwise, you'd need the `0,` address syntax for sed which is a GNU extension).

The `LC_ALL=C` is prepended to `sort` to ensure no locale settings change the order of the dates.

Comment: can I ask how to use you code in bash script ? or give one liner example

Comment: @KingDavid:  I copied the code directly from a bash script. I don't understand your question.

Comment: I suspect that what @KingDavid means that your code is not readable to people that aren't highly experienced in bash, and is not explained in your answer.

Comment: There already was explanation, I tried to expand it. Let me know if you have any particular questions.

Comment: @KingDavid - regarding "or give one liner example" - it's very unlikely that cramming the code onto one line will make it easier to understand.

Comment: 1 - What are you using the curly braces for? I understand that in theory you should run them all as one command and get the output there of as a single output. I don't understand why you would need this. 2 - What are you using the ' ///' for? 3 - What does the `sed` command do? It is unclear and is not the most common usage of `sed`.

Comment: @Uberhumus: 1. The curlies are used to pipe the output of all three commands into `sort`. There are other ways to get the same effect, YMMV. It's needed to get the generated date into the output so we can later find it with sed and remove the newer files.

Comment: @Uberhumus: 2. The `///`, as explained, is used to mark the date "30 days ago". It can never be part of a path, so that's how `sed` can identify the inserted date. 3. The sed command removes everything from line 1 to the line containing the `///`.

Comment: I love this, but it's getting line *since* instead of *older*. Flipping it removes the need for the `echo`, too: `{ date -d '-30 days' +%Y-%m-%d' ///'; cat /tmp/file; } | LC_ALL=C sort | sed '\=///=,$d'`

Answer (score 2):

```
OMA=$(date --date='1 month ago' +%Y-%m-%d)
while IFS= read -r line
do
  line_date=$(echo "$line" | cut -f 1 -d " ")
  if [[ $(date -d  "$line_date" +%s) -ge $(date -d "$OMA" +%s) ]]
  then
    echo "$line" >> /tmp/updated_file.txt
  fi
done < "/tmp/file"
```

Eplaination:

1. Create the date for "One Month Ago" as a variable, in seconds.
2. Go over lines and compare the date in them to the `$OMA` and add the relevant ones to the updated file.

---

Alternative implementation of the above:

```
oma=$(date --date='1 month ago' +%s)
while IFS= read -r line
do
  line_date="${line%% *}"
  if [[ $(date -d  "$line_date" +%s) -ge "$oma" ]]
  then
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  fi
done < "/tmp/file" > /tmp/updated_file.txt
```

Comment: You should copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it'll tell you about as it contains some anti-patterns and other issues.

Comment: @EdMorton on it.

Comment: You might also find https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) useful as shellcheck may not catch everything. Consider also that `line_date=$(echo $line | cut -f 1 -d " ")` can be done using just shell builtins `line_date="${line%% *}"` if you still have that in your code after the changes shellcheck recommends.

Comment: Oh, and you definitely should read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) - that's a major issue that shellcheck wouldn't tell you about.

Comment: @EdMorton, like this?

Comment: Yes, that solves the issues that shellcheck would tell you about and is a big improvement. Would you mind a few additional suggestions?

Comment: Are you kidding?! I'd love them! I'm getting a free private lesson here! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255679/discussion-between-uberhumus-and-ed-morton).

Comment: OK, I updated your answer to add a script with - 1) changed `OMA` to lower case as it's not an exported environment variable and so should not be all upper case, 2) calculate todays time in seconds just once instead of every time through the loop, 3) redirect the ouptut of the whole loop instead of each iteration, 4) use printf instead of echo for robustness and portability, 5) use a shell builtin instead of echo+cut+pipe strip of everything after a blank.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no solution for the bigger problem that you should never write a shell loop just to manipulate text :-). A shell loop like that takes far more code than an awk (the mandatory POSIX general-purpose text-processing tool available on all Unix boxes) script, requires more complicated (hard to get right, often buggy/fragile) code than an awk script, is less portable than an awk script, and would be orders of magnitude slower than an awk script.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside...
Be wary of quick, simple solutions that don't consider relevant details.

For example, from your given criteria and data, consider this one-liner:

```
sed /^$(date -d '-30 days' +%F)/Q /tmp/file # DO NOT USE THIS!
```

On my PC it produces *exactly* the same output as Ed's `awk` solution on your given sample data, but by comparison is actually *terribly broken*.

IF the file is not, as it appears from your example, already sorted, this fails.

IF there is no entry in the file for the day in question, this fails.

If you don't have GNU `sed` handy, this *crashes*.

The `awk` solution, on the other hand, doesn't suffer from any of these problems, but if you don't take the time to examine your data and your approach, you might not realize the differences until it's too late.