# awk + export value to awk not passed

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am using the following `awk` (from my previous post - [how to get list of folders that older then 30 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77324494/how-to-get-list-of-folders-that-older-then-30-days) ) in order to print the folders that are older than `XX days` as the following example. Regarding this example we set 30 days as constant in `awk` syntax

```
    awk -v d="$(date -d '-30 days' +'%F')" '$1 < d' file
    2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0046
    2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0049
    2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0051
    2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0063
    2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0064
    2023-09-14 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0065
    2023-09-18 /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1693406696051_0107
```

Now we want to replace the constant `30 days` with a variable, and we changed the `awk` as the following, so we want to pass the `day` value to `awk`, as `day=100`

```
awk -v day=100 -v d="$(date -d '-day days' +'%F')" '$1 < d'  file
```

but we do not see the expected output, and the `day` setting is not affected at all.

Could you please point out my error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command substitution runs before Awk runs. Also, the single quotes prevent the variable from being interpolated by the shell.

The correct code would look something like

```
day=100
awk -v d="$(date -d "-$day days" +'%F')" '$1 < d'  file
```

Make sure you understand the difference between a shell variable and an Awk variable. The shell doesn't know anything about Awk, and vice versa. (Much like you don't know the names or values of variables in the code which is running your computer, unless it exposes an interface to let you inspect its current state.)

Answer (score 4):

```bash
awk -v day=100
```

When you use awk command line argument like above you are declaring a variable `day` with the value `100` to be used inside the `awk` command.

However what you are doing is this on command line (not inside the awk command):

```bash
-v d="$(date -d '-day days' +'%F')"
```

Here `days` is not known and will not be expanded either by shell or awk.

What you are trying can be using this way:

```bash
day=100
awk -v d="$(date -d "-$day days" +'%F')" '$1 < d' file
```